# Find the line number where an echo appear in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell

It is possible to make the following bash script to work as I said in the title?

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

echo_report() {
    echo "echo on line $1"
}

trap 'echo_report $LINENO' [sigspec]

#same code here

echo "hi"

#more code here
```

I don't know what should I use for `[sigspec]`...

If using `trap` is not possible, what other options do I have?

Comment: At what event do you want to trigger trap ?

Comment: @thom I thought I was clear: `echo "hi"`

Comment: `grep -n "echo" myscript.sh`?

Comment: Trap doesn't work that way. It reacts on signals emitted by the OS or an external program. You can, however, do something like `kill -SIGUSR1 $$`  and your trap would be `trap 'echo_report $LINENO' SIGUSR1`

Comment: You can use the `DEBUG` signal, but that is non-selective; it is triggered by (just about) every command, not just, say, `echo` commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap `echo` in a function, then use `caller` to display the line number:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo() {
    caller
    command echo "$@"
}

echo "hi"
```

Result:

```
$ bash foo.bash
8 foo.bash
hi
```

Comment: Why `command echo` and not `builtin echo` or even use `printf`? Do you really like the external command `echo`?

Comment: `command` doesn't force external. It just ignores functions. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins